# How to Achieve Expressive Dynamic Array Sorting in Swift

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, swift

As a discipline to just learn the Swift way of doing things I try avoid as much typecasting to NSWhatevers as possible, however, there are times like these where doing so is quite frustrating.

I have a table view controller with sortable headers for columns of data. The data I use is an array of objects. I want to sort the array by the field names in those objects. If the user taps the same column header button again, the sort order is reversed which means I have to keep track of the current sort direction for each field/column.

In Objective-C/NSArray APIs, it was pretty simple to do this dynamically. You just use an `NSSortDescriptor` with `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` on `NSArray` passing it the field/column name and the sort order and you got back what you need.

In Swift however, you cannot pass the field name dynamically as a string. Instead you have to specify explicitly which field you want to use which means you either have to setup a verbose switch or if/else construct or you have to define a dictionary that takes your sort field as the key and a closure as the value. The closure then is what gets passed to your sort function. I set this up in a playground just to see what I could figure out going with the dictionary/closure lookup route. Here's what I came up with using some dummy objects:

```
class Order {
    var orderNumber:String
    var invoiceNumber:String
    var orderDate:NSDate

    init(orderNumber:String, invoiceNumber:String, orderDate:NSDate) {
        self.orderNumber = orderNumber
        self.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber
        self.orderDate = orderDate
    }
}
```

I instantiate a few of them in an array like this:

```
var orders = [Order(orderNumber: "123456", invoiceNumber: "2342342", orderDate: NSDate()),
    Order(orderNumber: "332422", invoiceNumber: "848484", orderDate: NSDate()),
    Order(orderNumber: "423425", invoiceNumber: "488244", orderDate: NSDate())]
```

Then I create my lookup dictionary that provides the closure I want to sort with:

```
var sorters = [
    "orderNumber" :
        [true : { (o1: Order, o2: Order) -> Bool in return o1.orderNumber < o2.orderNumber },
        false : { (o1: Order, o2: Order) -> Bool in return o1.orderNumber > o2.orderNumber }],
    "invoiceNumber" :
        [true : { (o1: Order, o2: Order) -> Bool in return o1.invoiceNumber < o2.invoiceNumber },
            false : { (o1: Order, o2: Order) -> Bool in return o1.invoiceNumber > o2.invoiceNumber }],
    "orderDate" :
        [true : { (o1: Order, o2: Order) -> Bool in return o1.orderDate < o2.orderDate },
            false : { (o1: Order, o2: Order) -> Bool in return o1.orderDate > o2.orderDate }]
]
```

You're probably wondering what gives with the `true` and `false` keys. This is to determine whether it should be sorted ascending (true) or descending (false). You can see how this plays out when I go to actually run the sort:

```
var currentSortField = "invoiceNumber"
var ascending = false

orders.sort(sorters[currentSortField]![ascending]!)
```

**Note**: I had to also overload the greater than and less than operators for NSDate to get the comparison to work in the "orderDate" field:

```
func >(lhs:NSDate, rhs:NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}

func <(lhs:NSDate, rhs:NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
}
```

The background on this question I realize is a bit long, however, I am just a bit befuddled that Swift doesn't appear to have a more elegant solution for solving this problem and wanted to provide the complete solution I've come up with to date. Remember, the NSWhatever equivalent in this case is a one liner:

```
var sorted = (orders as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: currentSortField, ascending: ascending)])
```

**So here's the question.** Is there a more succinct, expressive, and idiomatic way to do this in Swift without resorting to Foundation APIs?

If you want to try out the playground I created to test this, you can get it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8m53bprzui50muq/Sorting.playground.zip?dl=0

**UPDATE** After a discussion with Matt in the comments, I went ahead and implemented a sorting closure that compromises by using `valueForKey:` after making my Order object inherit from NSObject. It is a compromise, but it keeps me from completely abandoning the Swift sort function altogether and yet I don't have to type a boat ton of code. It goes like this:

```
var currentSortField = "invoiceNumber"
var ascending = false

var sorter = { (o1: Order, o2: Order) -> Bool in
    if ascending {
        return (o1.valueForKey(currentSortField) as String) < (o2.valueForKey(currentSortField) as String)

    } else {
        return (o1.valueForKey(currentSortField) as String) > (o2.valueForKey(currentSortField) as String)

    }
}

orders.sort(sorter)
```

It's no one-liner, but it's an interesting compromise.

**UPDATE TO THE UPDATE**

That's actually not going to work unless all of the vars are strings--which they are not. This dies on `o1.valueForKey(currentSortField) as String` when the field in question is an NSDate and not a String.

Comment: "In Swift however, you cannot pass the field name dynamically as a string" Sorry, you lost me there - why can't you?

Comment: @matt Maybe I just phrased it wrong. In the sort closure, when you use $0.invoiceNumber, for example, you can't say $0."invoiceNumber" having passed the field name in that way.

Comment: Right, I see. And I presume you forbid me to say `valueForKey()` even if this class inherits from NSObject?

Comment: Indeed. Verboten! ;-) I use it when I have to, but I'm pretty set on trying to embrace a Swift approach to everything. Given that its roots are still there and viable, there's nothing wrong with using valueForKey and the like, however, I was hoping there was a little magic I was yet to discover that is pure Swift.

Comment: Right, but the "magic" of Swift is to take _away_ introspection, dynamic message-formation, and type-agnosticism. So when you hold up Objective-C and say "the NSWhatever equivalent in this case is a one liner", then you seem to be saying, "Now do that but without any of the dangerous-yet-addictively-powerful NSWhatever features that _made_ this a one-liner in the first place." Is that fair? I mean, let's see _you_ do it _in Objective-C_ without using any of those features. Your one-liner is crunchy-packed with crashability of just the sort Swift aims to prevent.

Comment: This is so philosophical. Definitely don't agree that the act of taking away those features is magic. I don't think anyone would ever define it that way. It may be fundamental and, by some estimations, important, however, it most definitely is not magic. Magic is when you go wow --> mind blown!

Comment: Well don't look at me. I was hoping the new language would be Ruby! Instead it's exactly the opposite.

Comment: Totally agree with you there. Ruby. Now that's a dynamic and expressive language.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear to me what kind of answer would satisfy you. Personally I think your solution is a good one. A more simple-minded version, for those having trouble following what you're doing, would be something like this:

```
struct Thing {
    var first:String
    var last:String
}
var arr = [Thing]()
arr.append(Thing(first:"Al", last:"Zork"))
arr.append(Thing(first:"Zelda", last:"Aardvark"))

var howToSort: ((Thing, Thing) -> Bool)

func sorter(thing1:Thing, thing2:Thing) -> Bool {
    return thing1.first < thing2.first
}
howToSort = sorter
let arr2 = sorted(arr, howToSort)

func sorter2(thing1:Thing, thing2:Thing) -> Bool {
    return thing1.last < thing2.last
}
howToSort = sorter2
let arr3 = sorted(arr, howToSort)
```

The point is simply that things like `sorter` and `sorter2` are things that can be stored and retrieved. And that's what saving the sort criteria depends on.

Now, it's also true that `sorter` and `sorter2` can't be formed *dynamically*, the way an NSSortDescriptor can, or applied *dynamically* and type-agnostically, the way KVC is doing when you sort using a sort descriptor. But Swift, as I said in my comment, is a language that deliberately lacks eval ("don't be eval!"), introspection, dynamic message formation (no `performSelector`), and type-agnosticism. You can generalize your solution somewhat using a generic, I suppose, but the real issue seems to me to be that you're now addicted to the "power" of those things and you want to go cold-turkey on them without actually giving them up. My job, as I see it, is to talk you off the ledge.

Of course, my *real* response to your question is: Hey, Objective-C and NSSortDescriptor are not going away, so what's the big deal?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It works and the shortest way

```
var array = [6,3,2,1,5,4]
```

Sort (ascending) its elements

```
array = array.sort { $0 < $1 }
print(array) 
result is  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```